# How to get the latest date from listed dates along with the total count?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below DataFrame, it has keys with different dates out of which I would like to display latest date together with the count for each of the key-id pairs.

Input data as below:

```
id  key  date 
11  222  1/22/2017
11  222  1/22/2015
11  222  1/22/2016 
11  223  9/22/2017 
11  223  1/22/2010 
11  223  1/22/2008
```

Code I have tried:

```
val counts = df.groupBy($"id",$"key").count()
```

I am getting the below output,

```
id  key  count 
11  222   3
11  223   3
```

However, I want like the output to be as below:

```
id  key  count maxDate 
11  222   3    1/22/2017 
11  223   3    9/22/2017
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Perform an `agg` on both fields

```
df.groupBy($"id", $"key").agg(count($"date"), max($"date"))
```

Output:

```
+---+---+-----------+-----------+
| _1| _2|count(date)|  max(date)|
+---+---+-----------+-----------+
| 11|222|          3|  1/22/2017|
| 11|223|          3|  9/22/2017|
+---+---+-----------+-----------+
```

**Edit**: The `as` option proposed in the other answer is pretty good too.

**Edit**: Comment below is true. You need to convert to a proper date format. You can check the other answer wich converts to timestamp or use `udf`

```scala
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SparkSession, functions}

val  simpleDateFormatOriginal:SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
val  simpleDateFormatDestination:SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")


val toyyyymmdd = (s:String) => {
  simpleDateFormatDestination.format(simpleDateFormatOriginal.parse(s))
}

val toddmmyyyy = (s:String) => {
  simpleDateFormatOriginal.format(simpleDateFormatDestination.parse(s))
}

val toyyyymmddudf = functions.udf(toyyyymmdd)
val toddmmyyyyyudf = functions.udf(toddmmyyyy)


df.withColumn("date", toyyyymmddudf($"date"))
 .groupBy($"id", $"key")
 .agg(count($"date"), max($"date").as("maxDate"))
 .withColumn("maxDate", toddmmyyyyyudf($"maxDate"))
```

Comment: This is not correct. `MM/dd/yyyy` is not a sorting friendly format. Consider `Seq("11/22/2017", "2/22/2017").toDF.agg(max("value"))`. Using `to_date` -> `date_format` might fix this, and keep the answer a bit different from the other one. Please let me know when you fix this, and I'll remove the vote.

Comment: I hate to say that, but you cannot use `SimpleDateFormat ` like this.  It is not thread safe, so with multiple executor threads, everything can happen.  For correctness it should be either synchronized, initialized for each call.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to transform the date into unixtime, do the aggregation and then convert it back again. This conversions to and from unixtime can be performed with `unix_timestamp` and `from_unixtime` respectively. When the date is in unixtime, the latest date can be selected by finding the maximum value. The only possible down-side of this approach is that the date format must be explicitly given.

```
val dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

val df2 = df.withColumn("date", unix_timestamp($"date", dateFormat))
  .groupBy($"id",$"key").agg(count("date").as("count"), max("date").as("maxDate"))
  .withColumn("maxDate", from_unixtime($"maxDate", dateFormat))
```

Which will give you:

```
+---+---+-----+----------+
| id|key|count|   maxDate|
+---+---+-----+----------+
| 11|222|    3|01/22/2017|
| 11|223|    3|09/22/2017|
+---+---+-----+----------+
```